# Pass PHP POST data to a Wordpress page with permalink rewrites on

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm working with an eCommerce gateway that passes transaction data back to my site after a completed sale via PHP POST data. I need to track this data with Google Analytics' eCommerce event tracking, and present a thank-you page.

Currently, I have the eCommerce site sending customers to /thankyou.php, which has

```
$total = $_POST["Total"];
```

(among other fields) in the header. And then I use Google's script to send the data to Analytics:

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    "<?php echo $orderid; ?>",           // order ID - required
    "<?php echo $storename; ?>",  // affiliation or store name
    "<?php echo $total; ?>",          // total - required
    "",           // tax
    "",              // shipping
    "<?php echo $city; ?>",       // city
    "<?php echo $state; ?>",     // state or province
    "<?php echo $country; ?>"            // country
  ]);
```

This works! Perfectly. **The problem is** : when I try and put the same code in Wordpress' header (or on a static page), none of the $_POST data comes through. All of the fields are blank. I'm assuming this is because I'm sending the data to something like "/thank-you/" instead of /thank-you.php.

Is there any way I can make a Wordpress page deal with $_POST data in the same way a .php page would?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To catch posted data, use wordpress's 'init' action to catch posted data, for example

```
add_action('init', 'ur_form_process_fun');

function ur_form_process_fun(){
 if(isset($_POST['unique_hidden_field'])) {
   // process $_POST data here
 }
}
```

You can put this code in your plugins file or your theme's functions.php file.

In above code ur_form_process_fun() function trigger at initializing stage of wordpress.

`unique_hidden_field` can be one of the unique transaction field returened to your site.

Hope this may solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I tried this, but all of the $_POST variables come back empty. Any suggestions?